# Source Sans Google Font not displaying on Windows 8 - all browsers

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I wonder if someone came across this before. I'm using a Google font `Source Sans` and the font is not being displayed in any browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE, all latest versions) at all on Windows 8, however it does display correctly on all browsers in Windows 7 and OS X.

Any ideas of what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Can you show the css for how you include the font

Comment: Seems to work for me on windows 8.1 and ie, ff and chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/2p6j11e6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you happen to be using the property `text-rendering`? I've found in rare cases it can cause web fonts to stop displaying.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick. Any more suggestions?

Comment: No further ideas unfortunately. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway!